# Using Back on Navigation Bar bugs UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have a NavigationBar at the top of a TableView. It looks nice opening/closing the search.

[image]

[image]

---

However, if I click on a button in a cell and get directed to another page (with segue); and then use **Back** button to unwind, it seems like bugged.

([image])

So it looks like it is pressed and opened but it shouldn't have. It should be looked like the top picture instead (just UIBarButtonItem - search button)

[image]

---

I couldn't figure out the issue creating this problem.

Please note that `< Back` is created automatically and I didn't write any code to create it. Is there something I am doing wrong?

---

**Update:** Added some snippets...

First, created a different class for handling the search

```
class SearchBarViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

  var searchBar : UISearchBar?
  var searchBarWrapper : UIView?
  var searchBarButtonItem : UIBarButtonItem?

  func constructSearchBar()
  {
     searchBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Search, target: self, action: "showSearchBar")
     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchBarButtonItem
  }

  func showSearchBar() {
          // styling & configuration
   }

  func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

     UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
         self.searchBar?.resignFirstResponder()
         self.searchBarWrapper?.alpha = 0
         }, completion: { (success) -> Void in
             self.searchBar = nil
             self.searchBarWrapper = nil
             self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.searchBarButtonItem
        })
    }
   }
```

And my ViewController:

```
 class ViewController: SearchBarViewController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      constructSearchBar()
   } 
 }
```

---

Regarding to **emrys57**'s answer, I tried adding `viewWillAppear()` in my ViewController but I couldn't make it work, as my cancel looks a little different:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // Here, I couldn't figure out what to put because
    // my searchBarCancelButtonClicked() needs searchBar and
    // forces me to use (!) but then it says, it's optional..
}
```

---

**The answer is...**

```
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    navigationItem.titleView = nil
    constructSearchBar()
 }
```

Comment: Are you using `UISearchController`?

Comment: How do you implement the `search`?

Comment: Check `viewWillDisappear` `viewDidDisappear` `viewWillAppear` `viewDidAppear` cause these methods will execute when u go to 2nd viewController and come back

Comment: @Troy, I am using `UISearchBar`. @WarifAkhandRishi how can I detect/ prevent this issue? I am calling the createSearchBar() function in NavigationController's `viewDidLoad()` which creates the barButtonSystemItem as .Search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not posted code, so it's not entirely clear what's gone wrong. Using `UISearchBar`, I think you must be handling the buttons separately yourself, as opposed to using `UISearchController`. I think that you may not be clearing away the search bar when coming back from the second VC. This code clears out the search bar in `viewWillAppear`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var cancelButton: UIBarButtonItem?
var searchButton: UIBarButtonItem?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Cancel, target: self, action: Selector("searchCancelPressed:"))
    searchButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Search, target: self, action: Selector("searchPressed:"))
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    searchCancelPressed(nil)
}

func searchPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    navigationItem.titleView = UISearchBar()
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = cancelButton
}

func searchCancelPressed(sender: AnyObject?) {
    navigationItem.titleView = nil
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchButton
}

}
```

and that is working nicely for me when I do a push from a button to the second VC and then hit `back`.

Following the edit to the original question, this code seems to work, although it may not be the most elegant way of constructing the answer:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationItem.titleView = nil
    searchBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Search, target: self, action: "showSearchBar")
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchBarButtonItem
}
```

The function `constructSearchBar` no longer needs to be called in `viewDidLoad`, and can be deleted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried adding `viewWillAppear()` bit in my code, but I couldn't make it work as my cancel looks a little different. I have just added my snippet code in my question. Can you please check it and guide me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does that edited answer work? It's looking good on my iPad, with your code.

Comment: Nope, this is my one that doesn't work. But I couldn't figure out what I should exactly do in viewWillAppear(). Shouldn't I call my searchBarCancelButtonClicked() in viewWillAppear? My problem is that it when I use `< Back`, it doesn't initialise completely so it bugs. I am very confused man

Comment: The critical line is `navigationItem.titleView = nil`. If you miss that out, the searchBar comes back when you hit <back>. You can call `searchBarCancelButtonClicked` in `viewWillAppear` if you want, but you need to add `navigationItem.titleView = nil` to the completion routine there.

Comment: Thanks for the tick! Glad to be of help. Have fun!